# Which OpenGL / 3d Framework is used by Android game's developer?

Tags: android, open-source, opengl-es, 3d, game-physics

This is just a curiosity question. 
I've started developing with AndEngine a 2d openGL game engine and I was wondering which engines the big sw houses are using to develop a game.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unity3d](http://www.unity3d.com) is being used by a lot of of professional developers and software houses. It is very popular because of its simplicity and many consider it the best engine among those that cost less than a million dollars.

Those developing popular high level games use purchased/custom developed engines, many of which are pretty expensive.

Unreal Engine is another example.

Here is a list: http://www.xing.com/net/androids/android-game-engines-engines-list-553242/android-game-engines-engines-list-29951892/

Comment: Yes I know Unity3d or ShiVa3D but I think that they are really to expensive at the moment for a random developer or a single developer :)

Comment: You asked about big software houses, they can purchase the Android version of Unity3d (which is not free).

Answer (score 1):

[min3d](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) might be worth looking into.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, thank you very much :) What about 3d physics? I think that a 3d game engine have to include also that